# gyp install errors with docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to upgrade a project from Node 16 (16.17.1) to 18 (18.12.0). Locally everything works after I rebuild packages, but I'm getting failures in my Docker image.

Previous the image used the [Node 16 buster slim image](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/8edd510a1b2f64330fd7b865afd12d88c3c21679/16/buster-slim/Dockerfile), and now I'm using the [Node 18 version of the same image](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/f05fbf88068ba29ac9b544a72c9471ba60243e4b/18/bullseye-slim/Dockerfile). Digging into the logs from failure to install two packages (`sodium-native@npm:3.2.1` and `libxmljs2@npm:0.29.0`) I get errors because libtool is not installed and Python is not installed, respectively.

This seems strange though because comparing the two images there's nothing obvious to indicate I would see this error.

Any idea why I'm seeing these errors building the Docker image after upgrading to Node 18?

I'm using `yarn` to install packages rather than `npm` in case you think that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Debian 11 (bullseye) has removed the "python" package and the '/usr/bin/python' symlink due to the deprecation of Python 2](https://wiki.debian.org/Python#:%7E:text=NOTE%3A%20Debian%2011%20(bullseye)%20has%20removed%20the%20%22python%22%20package%20and%20the%20%27/usr/bin/python%27%20symlink%20due%20to%20the%20deprecation%20of%20Python%202.).

The image has upgraded its debian base and now it doesn't have the deps you need.

In the new image it is based on `FROM debian:bullseye-slim` and the old one it is based on `FROM debian:buster-slim`.

You could install it in your dockerfile, or use a different image which has these deps.

Comment: ah, thank you! i didn't want to install additional dependencies unnecessarily, but if they've been removed from the image then i guess there's no harm in adding them back since i used to have them

Comment: plan to accept this answer once i confirm this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error lately. In my case, I was using the [docker-python-nodejs](https://github.com/nikolaik/docker-python-nodejs) as a base image. The issue has gone after I changed the tag from:

```
python3.10-nodejs20-slim
```

to:

```
python3.10-nodejs20-bullseye
```